# How can I ORDER the result after i've used LIMIT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

This is kind of straight forward.
I want to `ORDER BY date DESC Limit 4` and then I want to `ORDER BY date ASC` on that result, so just 4-games from the middle of the big table with ASC date order, any ideas?
Just `ORDER BY date ASC Limit 4` Does not work!

What I have:
[image]

What I get:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use subquery :

```
SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY date DESC Limit 4) a ORDER BY a.Date
```

Comment: @Rocksteady : glad to help, don't worry about second order performance it's should only order 4 rows! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the last four rows from table

```
select * from table  order by date desc limit 0,4
```

if you want to get the first four rows from table

```
select * from table  order by date asc limit 0,4
```

Comment: Thank you but when I want four game from the middle of the table this will not cut it